# Maze Solving Algorithm in C++

Tags: c++

I'm writing an algorithm that finds its way through a maze by sticking to a wall and moving in this order: Down - Right - Up - Left until it finds the exit. But, sometimes, it gets stuck in an infinite loop and is unable to continue. I've been trying to figure out what is wrong for hours and I've had no luck. Here's the code

```
#include <iostream>
#include <windows.h>
const int MazeWidth = 30;
const int MazeHeight = 20;
const char MazeExit = '$';
const char Wall = '#';
const char Free = ' ';
const unsigned char SomeDude = 254;
COORD MazeExitCoords;
COORD StartingPoint;

using namespace std;
char Maze [MazeHeight][MazeWidth];




void FillDaMaze(){

    MazeExitCoords.X = MazeWidth - 20;
    MazeExitCoords.Y = 2;
    StartingPoint.X = 3;
    StartingPoint.Y = MazeHeight - 3;

    for(int i = 0; i < MazeHeight; i++){

        for(int ii = 0; ii < MazeWidth; ii++){

            if(i == 0 || i == MazeHeight - 1 || ii == 0 || ii == MazeWidth - 1){
                Maze[i][ii] = Wall;
            }
            else{
            Maze[i][ii] = Free;
            }

            if(i == MazeExitCoords.Y && ii == MazeExitCoords.X){
                    Maze[i][ii] = MazeExit;
            }
            else if(i == StartingPoint.Y && ii == StartingPoint.X){
                    Maze[i][ii] = SomeDude;
            }
        }
    }
}
void PrintDaMaze(int color){
    SetConsoleTextAttribute(GetStdHandle(STD_OUTPUT_HANDLE),color);

    for(int i = 0; i < MazeHeight; i++){

        for(int ii = 0; ii < MazeWidth;ii++){

            cout << Maze[i][ii];
        }
        cout << endl;
    }
}
void FindYourWayThroughTheMaze(){



        if(Maze[StartingPoint.Y + 1][StartingPoint.X] != Wall && Maze[StartingPoint.Y + 1][StartingPoint.X ] != SomeDude){
        StartingPoint.Y++;



        }
        else if(Maze[StartingPoint.Y][StartingPoint.X + 1] != Wall && Maze[StartingPoint.Y][StartingPoint.X + 1] != SomeDude){
            StartingPoint.X++;



        }
        else if(Maze[StartingPoint.Y - 1][StartingPoint.X] != Wall && Maze[StartingPoint.Y - 1][StartingPoint.X ] != SomeDude){
            StartingPoint.Y--;





        }
        else if(Maze[StartingPoint.Y][StartingPoint.X - 1] != Wall && Maze[StartingPoint.Y][StartingPoint.X - 1] != SomeDude){
            StartingPoint.X--;



        }


    Maze[StartingPoint.Y][StartingPoint.X] = SomeDude;

}
int main(){

FillDaMaze();
PrintDaMaze(10);
while(StartingPoint.X != MazeExitCoords.X || StartingPoint.Y != MazeExitCoords.Y){
    FindYourWayThroughTheMaze();
    system("CLS");
    PrintDaMaze(10);
    Sleep(50);
}


}
```

Comment: i started to code only a couple months ago but i thought i could help since i had this assignement in school. My teacher said that to avoid looping forever, we had to use an srand() to randomize the decision of the direction.
i hope i helped...

Answer (score 24):

[image]

To have a chance in solving it, you must:

- Create a `Solve()` routine and recursively call itself:

  - if 1st, 2nd, 3rd, ... are true `Solve` has succeeded in finding a solution
  - if 1st, 2nd, 3rd, ... contains a false, it has to backtrack and find another way
- You need to build a buffer of places you've been to avoid infinite loops

  - as you make moves it needs to keep tabs on it
  - when we hit a dead end, we need to erase bad moves
  - we can implement the above by burning in a guess and removing it if it's wrong

Here's a crude implementation based on the above concepts:

```
#include <stdio.h>

const int mazeRows = 9;
const int mazeColumns = 9;
char maze[mazeRows][mazeColumns + 1] = {
    "# #######",
    "#   #   #",
    "# ### # #",
    "# #   # #",
    "# # # ###",
    "#   # # #",
    "# ### # #",
    "#   #   #",
    "####### #",
};
const char wall = '#';
const char free = ' ';
const char someDude = '*';

class COORD
{
public:
    int x;
    int y;
    COORD(int _x = 0, int _y = 0) { x = _x, y = _y; }
    COORD(const COORD &coord) { x = coord.x; y = coord.y; }
};
COORD startingPoint(1, 0);
COORD endingPoint(7, 8);

void printDaMaze() {
    for (int Y = 0; Y < mazeRows; Y++) {
        printf("%s\n", maze[Y]);
    }
    printf("\n");
}

char get(int x, int y) {
    if (x <= 0 || x >= mazeColumns || y <= 0 || y >= mazeRows) return wall;
    return maze[y][x];
}

void set(int x, int y, char ch) {
    if (x <= 0 || x >= mazeColumns || y <= 0 || y >= mazeRows) return;
    maze[y][x] = ch;
}

bool solve(int x, int y) {
    // Make the move (if it's wrong, we will backtrack later.To illustrate, I have a version of the above in Javascript:
    // If you want progressive update, uncomment these lines...
    //printDaMaze();
    //sleep(50);
    // Check if we have reached our goal.
    if (x == endingPoint.x && y == endingPoint.y) return true;
    // Recursively search for our goal.
    if (get(x - 1, y) == free && solve(x - 1, y)) return true;
    if (get(x + 1, y) == free && solve(x + 1, y)) return true;
    if (get(x, y - 1) == free && solve(x, y - 1)) return true;
    if (get(x, y + 1) == free && solve(x, y + 1)) return true;
    // Otherwise we need to backtrack and find another solution.
    set(x, y, free);
    // If you want progressive update, uncomment these lines...
    //printDaMaze();
    //sleep(50);
    return false;
}

int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
    if (solve(startingPoint.x, startingPoint.y)) {
        printDaMaze();
        printf("Solved!\n");
    } else {
        printf("Cannot solve. :-(\n");
    }
    return 0;
}
```

To illustrate, I have a version of the above running in JavaScript:

```js
const mazeColumns = 9;
const mazeRows = 9;

let maze = [
    "# #######",
    "#   #   #",
    "# ### # #",
    "# #   # #",
    "# # # ###",
    "#   # # #",
    "# ### # #",
    "#   #   #",
    "####### #"
].map(line => line.split(''));
const wall = '#';
const free = ' ';
const someDude = '*';
const startingPoint = [1, 0];
const endingPoint = [7, 8];

function printDaMaze() {
    //maze.forEach(line => console.log(line.join('')))
    let txt = maze.reduce((p, c) => p += c.join('') + '\n', '')
    let html = txt.replace(/[*]/g, c => '<font color=red>*</font>')
    $('#mazeOutput').html(html);
}

function get(x, y) {
    if (x <= 0 || x >= mazeColumns || y <= 0 || y >= mazeRows) return wall;
    return maze[y][x];
}

function set(x, y, ch) {
    if (x <= 0 || x >= mazeColumns || y <= 0 || y >= mazeRows) return;
    maze[y][x] = ch;
}

async function solve(x, y) {
    // Make the move (if it's wrong, we will backtrack later.
    set(x, y, someDude);
    printDaMaze();
    await sleep(100);
    // Check if we have reached our goal.
    if (x === endingPoint[0] && y === endingPoint[1]) return true
    // Recursively search for our goal.
    if (get(x - 1, y) === free && await solve(x - 1, y)) return true;
    if (get(x + 1, y) === free && await solve(x + 1, y)) return true;
    if (get(x, y - 1) === free && await solve(x, y - 1)) return true;
    if (get(x, y + 1) === free && await solve(x, y + 1)) return true;
    // Otherwise we need to backtrack and find another solution.
    set(x, y, free);
    printDaMaze();
    await sleep(100);
    return false;
}

function sleep(ms) {
    return new Promise((resolve) => setTimeout(resolve, ms));
}

(async function() {
    if (await solve(startingPoint[0], startingPoint[1])) {
        console.log("Solved!");
    } else {
        console.log("Cannot solve. :-(");
    }
})();
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<pre id="mazeOutput">
</pre>
```

Answer (score 6):

As Luchian already posted, the algorithm (even if implemented correctly) is not suitable to find your way out of all sort of mazes: If you have some loop inside your maze, you might just end up running around this looping wall.

Also, as it seems, you don't really generate a maze but rather a big field with walls at the borders and the "exit" somewhere inside it. An algorithm, which really "sticks to a wall" will never find the exit, if the exit is not near the wall (which, again, is currently only at the borders of your "maze").

Since you're not removing the `SomeDude`s, i.e. the positions you've already been, and you're treating `SomeDude` the same way as a `Wall`, you're slowly filling up the maze with some kind of "SomeDude-Wall": You go just down until you hit the border and then go in big counterclockwise spirals around the field, leaving a trace of `SomeDude`s.

Depending on your starting point and the exit, you can easily run into the situation, where all four directions are blocked, either by a "real" wall or by some previous `SomeDude` you left there. Then, none of the four `if`-Statements is executed and you just have an infinite loop (since nothing is changed inside the loop body).

For an algorithm, wich sticks to a wall (and thus would be able to find a way out of *some kinds of mazes*), I would suggest the following steps:

- First, go into one direction, until you hit a wall.
- Set your current *direction*, so that the wall is at your right side.
- Follow your current direction (don't forget to delete your `SomeDude`-trace) until either

  - You've found the exit.
  - There is no wall at your right side: In this case, turn right and go one step forward.
  - Or, there is a wall just in front of you. In this case, turn *left* until the way ahead of you is free

This way, you ensure, that there is always "the same" wall at your right side, so you "stick" to that wall.

Remember, that this algorithm cannot find exits, if the exit is inside some free space (since it always stick to a wall, the exit must also be near a wall to be found).

For an algorithm which finds its way out of all possible mazes, you need to have some sort of *backtracking*: Remeber every point, where you have multiple choices to continue. Choose one way, and follow it. If it's a dead-end, go back to tha last point of decision and take the next choice. If no way leads to the exit, go to the previous last point and so on. This is a recursive approach, known as "depth-first-search" in graph theory (feel free to do a bit of googling, I'm confident, you'll find a lot of material about this :) ...)

HTH
Martin