# find a path in maze using recursion

Tags: c++, recursion, maze

Hi~I got stuck in this problem. Someone please help me!!!!

The problem is that the program will ask the user to input a number between 4 and 20 to decide the size of the maze. It will later ask the user to input the contents of the maze row by row and store it into a 2D bool array (true means blocked and false means clear). Then the program starts at the top left corner and tries to find a path leading to the lower right corner (can move right, left, up, down). At this time, the program should also maintain another char array which record the path found (if there's any) and print it out at the end of processing. This problem asks to use recursion to solve it.

Here's what I got now:

```
#include<iostream>

using namespace std;

int row, col;
int size=0;
bool  maze[21][21]; 
char print[22][22];
const char start = 's', up = 'u', down = 'd', left = 'l', right = 'r', barrier = 'x';

char path(int coorx, int coory, int size)
{
    if(maze[coorx][coory+1]=0)
    {   
        print[coorx+1][coory+2]='r';
        return path(coorx,coory+1,size);
    }
    else
    {
        if(maze[coorx+1][coory]=0)
        {
            print[coorx+2][coory+1]='d';
            return path(coorx+1,coory,size);
        }
        else
        {
            if(maze[coorx][coory-1]=0)
            {
                print[coorx+1][coory]='l';
                return path(coorx,coory-1,size);
            }
            else
            {
                if(maze[coorx-1][coory]=0)
                {
                    print[coorx][coory+1]='u';
                    return path(coorx-1,coory,size);
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

int main()
{

    while(size<4 || size>20) 
    {
        cout<<"Please input size of maze (a number between 4 and 20 is expected) -> ";
        cin >>size;

        if(size<4 || size>20)
            cout<<"**Error** maze size not in range!"<<endl;
    }

    cout<<"Please input contents of maze row by row, 1 for barrier and 0 for free passage."<<endl;
    cout<<endl;
    for(int i=1; i<size+1; i++)
    {
        for(int j=1; j<size+1; j++)
            cin>>maze[i][j];
    }

    if(maze[1][1]==1)
        cout<<"**Error** entrance to maze is blocked!"<<endl;
    else
    {
        // find the path
        for(int coorx=0;coorx<size;coorx++)
        {
            for(int coory=0;coory<size;coory++)
                path(coorx,coory,size);
        }


        cout<<"The maze and the path:"<<endl;

        // print the forum (adding characters '+','-', ' ')
        print[0][0]=print[size+1][size+1]=print[0][size+1]=print[size+1][0]='+';
        print[1][1]='s';
        for(int x=1; x<size+1; x++)
        {
            for(int y=0; y<size+2; y++){
                if(y==0 || y==size+1)
                {
                        print[x][y]='|';
                }
            }

        }

        for(int x=0; x<size+2; x++)
        {
            for(int y=0; y<size+2; y++){
                if(x==0 || x== size+1){
                    if(y!=0 && y!=size+1)
                    print[x][y]='-';
                }
            }

        }


        for(int row=0; row<size+2; row++)
        {
            for(int col=0; col<size+2; col++)
            {
                if(maze[row][col]==1)
                    print[row][col]='x';
            }
        }

        // print out the record of the path found
        for(int row=0; row<size+2; row++)
        {
            for(int col=0; col<size+2; col++){
                cout<<print[row][col];
            }

            cout << endl;
        }
    }
    return 0;
}
```

I don't know why I can't show those 'r', 'd', 'l', 'u'. I already assigned them to `print[][]`, but why it won't show why I print out the `print[][]`??

New coding

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;

int row,col;
int size=0;
bool  maze[20][20]; 
char print[22][22];

bool path(int coorx, int coory, int size)
{
if(coorx==size-1 && coory==size-1)
    return true;
if(!maze[coorx][coory+1] && path(coorx,coory+1,size))
    return true;
    return 'r';
if(!maze[coorx+1][coory] && path(coorx+1,coory,size))
    return true;
    return 'd';
if(!maze[coorx][coory-1] && path(coorx,coory-1,size))
    return true;
    return 'l';
if(!maze[coorx-1][coory] && path(coorx-1,coory,size))
    return true;
    return 'u';
}

int main()
{

while(size<4 || size>20) 
{
    cout<<"Please input size of maze (a number between 4 and 20 is expected) -> ";
    cin >>size;

    if(size<4 || size>20)
        cout<<"**Error** maze size not in range!"<<endl;
}

cout<<"Please input contents of maze row by row, 1 for barrier and 0 for free passage."<<endl;
cout<<endl;
for(int i=0; i<size; i++)
{
    for(int j=0; j<size; j++)
        cin>>maze[i][j];
}

if(maze[0][0]==1)
    cout<<"**Error** entrance to maze is blocked!"<<endl;
else
{
    int row=0;
    int col=0;
    path(row,col,size);

    if(!path(row,col,size))
    {
        cout<<"**Warning** no path from entrance to exit!"<<endl;
    }
    else
    {
        if('r')
            print[row+2][col+3]='r';
        if('d')
            print[row+3][col+2]='d';
        if('l')
            print[row+2][col+1]='l';
        if('u')
            print[row+1][col+2]='u';
    }

    cout<<"The maze and the path:"<<endl;

    // print the forum (adding characters '+','-', ' ')
    print[0][0]=print[size+1][size+1]=print[0][size+1]=print[size+1][0]=='+';
    print[1][1]='s';
    for(int x=1; x<size+1; x++)
    {
        for(int y=0; y<size+2; y++){
            if(y==0 || y==size+1)
            {
                    print[x][y]=='|';
            }
        }

    }

    for(int x=0; x<size+2; x++)
    {
        for(int y=0; y<size+2; y++){
            if(x==0 || x== size+1){
                if(y!=0 && y!=size+1)
                print[x][y]=='-';
            }
        }

    }


    for(int row=0; row<size; row++)
    {
        for(int col=0; col<size; col++)
        {
            if(maze[row][col]==1)
                print[row+1][col+1]=='x';
        }
    }

    path(0,0,size);

    // pirnt out the record of the path found
    for(int row=0; row<size+2; row++)
    {
        for(int col=0; col<size+2; col++){
            cout<<print[row][col];
        }

        cout << endl;
    }
}
return 0;
}
```

for maze size=4

```
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
0 0 0 0
```

the sample run looks like

```
s r r r
      d
      d
      d
```

but my program run like this

```
s r
```

nothing afterward, don't know why

Comment: Is it homework or interview questions?

Answer (score 3):

1. In your `if(maze[coorx][coory+1]=0)` (and similar) statements in `path()`, the single equals is the assignment operator, so it'll always evaluate to false.

   Since `maze` is a bool array, you should just use `if(!maze[coorx][coory + 1])`.
2. `print` should probably be a one dimensional array instead of a two dimensional array since it only needs to keep track of "r", "l", "d", and "u", and not the cells where you take those actions.
3. In `path()`, you're `return`ing early instead of backtracking. You should return only if a path exists, and you can tell whether a path exists by recursing.

   In other words, the `path()` function needs to be rewritten to look something like this:

   ```
   /* returns true if there's a path to the bottom right cell, otherwise false */
   bool path(int coorx, int coory, int size) {
       if(coorx == size - 1 && coory == size - 1) { // exit of maze
           return true;
       }
       if(!maze[coorx][coory + 1] && path(coorx, coory + 1, size)) {
           // add "right" to your path
           return true;
       }
       if(!maze[coorx + 1][coory] && path(coorx + 1, coory, size)) {
           // add "down" to your path
           return true;
       }
       // etc...
   }
   ```

   Of course, you should add bounds checking as well.

   And, `path` will be backwards at the end of the recursion, but you can just reverse it.
4. You should call the `path()` function just once at the top left cell, not at each and every cell. Recursion will handle the search through all cells of the maze.
5. `if(maze[1][1]==1)` in `main()` should probably be `if(maze[0][0])` instead, since you're apparently trying to start at the top left cell.

#### Edit:

6. Once you get the recursion working, you can simply add to `print` in `path()`:

   ```
   bool path(int coorx, int coory, int size, int depth) {
       // if(coorx == size - 1 ... base case
       if(!maze[coorx][coory + 1] && path(coorx, coory + 1, size, depth + 1)) {
           print[coorx][coory + 1] = 'r';
           return true;
       }
       // etc...
   }
   ```
7. You're calling `path()` three times in `main()`. Just call it once and store the result in a boolean.
8. You're not printing the path correctly. The sample output prints out the character for each cell in `print` -- you should do the same.

Comment: Thanks! I have already modified ,but the program stop running and got error after I input the contents of maze. It can't run the     path()

Comment: .exe file will stop running and windows will ask me to shut it down

Comment: Sounds like an infinite loop? I'd suggest that you try to get `path()` to output true or false first, before worrying about `print`.

Comment: Actually, it could also be that there are too many paths -- try inputting `size = 4` or something small.

Comment: yeah i input size = 4 and even the content is like all '0', but still doesn't work

Comment: Your edited `path()` looks right, but in `main()` all you really need is `if(path(0, 0, size)) { cout << "path found"; } else { cout << "no path found" << endl; }`.

Comment: but I need to print out 'r' if the path go right, etc.

Comment: I think you should just make the search work before you start worrying about the path. Or does it work already?

Comment: I've update the path(0,0,size) part in main() in the New coding in my original questions

Comment: I edit it to be    `bool path(int coorx, int coory, int size){//skip....if(!maze[coorx][coory+1]){coory++;print[coorx][coory]='r';return true;return path(coorx,coory,size)}`      is this correct?

Comment: No, the point is that you make the recursive call in the if statement. I suggest you look at [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/9192067/485971) if you don't understand backtracking through a maze.