# C++ Recursive Maze Solver looping infinitely

Tags: c++, class, recursion, solver, maze

I am new to C++ and am trying to write a program that reads a file, dynamically creates a 2D array, and fills the array with input from the file. Then it solves the maze using recursion. The text file looks like this:

[image: The "maze.txt" file]

The first 4 numbers dictate the amount of rows, amount of columns, and starting position (X,Y). "S" is the start, "O" the path, and "E" the end. I have no trouble with creating the array or filling the array, but when running the program, it encounters an error when calling the recursive function to solve the maze. This is the function:

```
bool mazeSolve(char **maze, int startRow, int startCol){
        
  char test = maze[startRow][startCol];
              
  //If maze finds end stop program (Base Case)
  if (test == 'E'){
     cout << "End reached" << endl;
     return true;
  }//End if for base case
       
  //If function can go right
  if (maze[startRow][startCol+1] == 'O'){
     maze[startRow][startCol] = 'P';
     return mazeSolve(maze, startRow, startCol+1);
  }
  
  //If function can go left
  if (maze[startRow][startCol-1] == 'O'){
     maze[startRow][startCol] = 'P';
     return mazeSolve(maze, startRow, startCol-1);
  }
  
  //If function can go up
  if (maze[startRow-1][startCol] == 'O' && startRow-1 >= 0){
     maze[startRow][startCol] = 'P';
     return mazeSolve(maze, startRow-1, startCol);
  }
  
  //If function can go down
  if (maze[startRow+1][startCol] == 'O'){
     maze[startRow][startCol] = 'P';
     return mazeSolve(maze, startRow+1, startCol);
  }
  
  //If function cannot find O's then it will backtrack
  //If function reaches wall, backtrack down
  if (maze[startRow+1][startCol] == 'P'){
        maze[startRow][startCol] = 'C';
        return mazeSolve(maze, startRow+1, startCol);
  }
  
  //If function reaches wall, backtrack up
  if (startRow-1 >= 0 && maze[startRow-1][startCol] == 'P'){
        maze[startRow][startCol] = 'C';
        return mazeSolve(maze, startRow-1, startCol);
  }
  
  //If function reaches wall, backtrack left
  if (maze[startRow][startCol-1] == 'P'){
        maze[startRow][startCol] = 'C';
        return mazeSolve(maze, startRow, startCol-1);
  }
  
  //If function reaches wall, backtrack right
  if (maze[startRow][startCol+1] == 'P'){
        maze[startRow][startCol] = 'C';
        return mazeSolve(maze, startRow, startCol+1);
  }
```

I have googled and searched this site for similar problems but I seem to have a fundamental misunderstanding of recursion as I can't follow the solutions. I thought the bottom half would allow the function to backtrack until it found a new "O" and eventually an "E", but it is looping infinitely. My professor is asking for this to be done with if statements. Where did my logic go wrong? Any help would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: "it encounters an error " what error?

Comment: Did you debug your code? On the 1st glance, I made two observations: 1.) You don't check for array bounds. Think about what happens if `startCol` becomes 0 or 34. 2.) It seems that you didn't understand the term "backtracking". When you backtrack I would expect to return from current recursion level to test another alternative from in an outer call. In your implementation, you make another recursive calls instead.

Comment: @pm100 My compiler (JGrasp) won't proceed past calling mazeSolve and the error code is for infinite loop.

Comment: @Scheff'sCat 1) Thank you, I forgot to account for that. 2) So if I want to return from current recursion, the backtracking if statements should be returning "false"? Then the recursion returns to the last call that can find an "O"?

Comment: This is a frequently asked question. See an answer I wrote some time back here: https://stackoverflow.com/a/9192067

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I figured it out after some debugging. Rewrote the function from scratch. Thank you for everyone for your help. I added an out of bounds check and added a condition for the if statements to check for both 'O' and 'E'. Weirdly the backtracking if statements remained the same, even though I thought they were the issue.:

```
bool mazeSolve(char **maze, int startRow, int startCol){      
            
      //Output test message
      char test = maze[startRow][startCol];
      //cout << test << endl;
                  
      //If maze finds end stop program (Base Case)
      if (test == 'E'){
         cout << "End reached" << endl;
         return true;
      }//End if for base case
      
      //Out of bounds check
      if (startRow < 0 || startCol < 0 || startRow >= arrayRowSize || 
          startCol >= arrayColSize){
          cout << "bounds error";
          return false;   
      }//End out of bounds if
      
      //If function can go down
      if (maze[startRow+1][startCol] == 'O' || maze[startRow+1][startCol] == 'E'){
         maze[startRow][startCol] = 'P';
         //cout << "down" << endl;
         return mazeSolve(maze, startRow+1, startCol);
      } //End down if
      
      //If function can go right
      if (maze[startRow][startCol+1] == 'O' || maze[startRow][startCol+1] == 'E'){
         maze[startRow][startCol] = 'P';
         //cout << "right" << endl;
         return mazeSolve(maze, startRow, startCol+1);
      } //End right if
      
      //If function can go left
      if (maze[startRow][startCol-1] == 'O' || maze[startRow][startCol-1] == 'E'){
         maze[startRow][startCol] = 'P';
         //cout << "left" << endl;
         return mazeSolve(maze, startRow, startCol-1);
      } //End left if
      
      //If function can go up
      if (maze[startRow-1][startCol] == 'O' || maze[startRow-1][startCol] == 'E'){
         maze[startRow][startCol] = 'P';
         //cout << "right" << endl;
         return mazeSolve(maze, startRow-1, startCol);
      } //End up if     
      
      //If function cannot find O's then it will backtrack
      //If function reaches wall, backtrack down
      if (maze[startRow+1][startCol] == 'P'){
            maze[startRow][startCol] = '*';
            return mazeSolve(maze, startRow+1, startCol);
      } //End backtrack down if
      
      //If function reaches wall, backtrack up
      if (maze[startRow-1][startCol] == 'P'){
            maze[startRow][startCol] = '^';
            return mazeSolve(maze, startRow-1, startCol);
      } //End backtrack up if
      
      //If function reaches wall, backtrack left
      if (maze[startRow][startCol-1] == 'P'){
            maze[startRow][startCol] = '<';
            return mazeSolve(maze, startRow, startCol-1);
      } //End backtrack left if
      
      //If function reaches wall, backtrack right
      if (maze[startRow][startCol+1] == 'P'){
            maze[startRow][startCol] = '>';
            return mazeSolve(maze, startRow, startCol+1);
            //End backtrack right if
      } else 
         return false;//If all else fails, maze is unsolvable            
}
```

This solves the maze. My only issue now is error handling if the maze does not have an end. I edited the txt file to have no "E", and the function loops infinitely. I thought the final "else" statement would cover this, but it doesn't. What should I have done to handle the case of an unsolvable maze?

Comment: I just was fiddling with your sample also... (as a warm-up before starting serious work). First, I made a version on my own: [Working 1st Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0d5d5aa6ca59936). I tried to make every check only once (on the cost of additional recursive calls). That worked fine. Then I tried to resemble your attempt closer. [Buggy 2nd Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/5f748b03d981d579) Even with the recommended fixes, it didn't work. Thinking why I came to the conclusion that the check for 'E' is missing. In this moment, your answer appeared. :-)

Comment: Concerning _What should I have done to handle the case of an unsolvable maze?_: I recommend to investigate (aka. debug) further. Try with a very small sample maze to make it less tedious. Then you can use print debugging (like in my [Working 1st Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/d0d5d5aa6ca59936)) or just use your debugger with single step. Btw. I applied the fix for 'E' as well and then tested with a maze without exit. [Fixed 2nd Demo on coliru](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/bd2eca2480162c24)

Comment: Btw. The backtracking part in your example is still wrong. Why do you think you need the last 4 "backtrack" tests? Backtracking doesn't mean to do additional calls. Backtracking is a feature of recursive search resulting from the fact that dead ends can be handled by returning false which (after returning to outer calls) may be used to search in a different direction.

Comment: @Scheff's Cat Thank you for your help. After some studying I think I can follow your code. It is still a bit overwhelming but it makes sense overall.

Answer (score 0):

When you backtrack, you first check if the search was successful, and then you try a different option if it wasn't, after reverting the attempt you just made.

An actual backtracking variant of your first non-base case would look like this:

```
if (maze[startRow][startCol+1] == 'O'){
     auto original = maze[startRow][startCol]; 
     maze[startRow][startCol] = 'P';
     if (mazeSolve(maze, startRow, startCol+1))
         return true;
     maze[startRow][startCol] = original;
}
// ... and keep going with the next attempt ...
```

Comment: I'm sorry I am still a bit confused. This block should be after my first four directional checks? If so, why is it checking for 'O' when the first four already have, shouldn't it be checking for 'P'? Or are you saying the "if (mazeSolve(...))" statement should be within the first four directional checks and acts as the recursive call? Won't returning "true" end the entirety of the recursive stack?

Comment: I'm saying that this should replace the `//If function can go right` block (I copied the wrong block).  Returning `true` means that the search was successful. If it wasn't, you continue and try a different direction, which is what "backtracking" is. And recursive functions work exactly like non-recursive functions; they return to the function that called them, not to some point earlier on in the "chain". There is no way to "end the entirety of the recursive stack". If you're not yet comfortable with recursive functions, study some simpler cases than an eight-branched one.

Comment: Thanks for your reply. I think I have a better grasp of recursion now and understand the algorithm better. So when the function finally finds 'E' it will return true through the chain which is what the nested if is for?